# Which guide to use for Google Analytics for Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

While i was trying to find the developers guide for adding Google Analytics for Android app, i found 2 guids.

1. with a json configuration file which required to have a Project created with Google Services
   The link for this is https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/app
2. with global_tracker.xml and without configuration (json) file.
   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Not sure which guide to follow. on other forums i have seen people using the (2) guide. and was wondering if i need the json configuration file at all.

Answer (score 1):

After researching and trying it out, i had to use Option (2) to have it working

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

I don't need the json file. I don't even need the global_tracker unless i want to change the default settings.